# How to Eager Load The Session Query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to figure out where laravel makes the session query, i have these queries when i just log in my app

```
/****************************** Database Queries ******************************/

   0.79 | select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1 | 1
   0.8 | select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`............

Queries: 2
Time: 1.59
/****************************** End Queries ***********************************/
```

I would like to eager load the first query with the second query, i use the second query in every pages of my website to get the user nav bar according with his role

if i do Auth::user()->roles()->id the second query would run.. but if i do User::with('Role')->find(1); for example i would get the same result as the first query plus+ the second.. am i right? how could i change this laravel behavior to runs trough all the pages.. i would save one query :)

hope i could explain myself clearly..

Comment: Use view::share('user', User::with('Role')->find(1);) within the basecontrollers constructor within app/controllers and extend all your controllers by this and all the views will include a user object.

Comment: No, eager loading doesn't save any query here, but you can use eloquent in a way that causes additional queries. So show the code.

Comment: @MattBurrow all the views already has an user object accessible by Auth::user(), what i really want to do is to make the Auth::user() eager loaded with Role so in the future when i do something like this Auth::user()->role->id it retrieves me the role without needing to querying again...

Comment: @RafaelMilewski once you have done the query and put it in to view share, it will be available in EVERY view on EVERY request, future proofing your app when you need the same object in a new view you create. More of a tip than an answer ;).

Comment: @MattBurrow yes i got the view:share, but it doesnt even change what i wanted to do.. as the first query runs normally and now i have a copy of the first query with the second one i want to attach.. so still have two queries.. if u run Auth::logout() and just refresh my app.. there will be 0 querry, if i Login and go to a blank page with nothing not even a layout.. i will have one query running.. that is the User query laravel will run every time to see if the user is logged in or not.. is specifically this query the one i want to change.. and eager load..